# How do Cryocoolers that use Helium as Coolant work?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was unable to find elaborate information on helium based Cryocoolers. I like to know how they use helium to cool samples to cryogenic temperatures and why helium is the best option as a coolant.

Answer (score 2):

A helium based cryocooler works just like an air conditioner, but helium is the gas rather than a halocarbon compound. The boiling point of helium is −268.928 °C, so such a cryocooler could get really cold.

Helium is a rare gas and relatively expensive. So to cool a small experimental apparatus it is much cheaper to buy one helium based cryocooler rather than dewars and dewars of liquid helium.

Comment: Could you tell me how it cools the samples?

Comment: http://inspirehep.net/record/852153/plots

The actual design depends on the experiment you want to perform, as you usually cool the sample for some reason, not just for fun.